# uploading file to dropbox

Tags: java, api, dropbox

I am trying to run an application using Dropbox core API.

The sample program will upload the file to my Dropbox account.
I got the app key and secret from the Dropbox. I tried to run the sample program, but got stuck. Facing some problem in authorizing the app.

The sample program will print a URL, we have to copy the URL in order to authorize the app. Then authorize the app by clicking allow, I am getting this message:

`"Enter this code into agri to finish the process".`

Regarding the code

```
{
    // Have the user sign in and authorize your app.
    String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();
    System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
    System.out.println("2. Click  (you might have to log in first)");
    System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");

            //got stuck over here
    String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().trim();      
 DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);

    DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, authFinish.accessToken);

    System.out.println("Linked account: " + client.getAccountInfo().displayName);

    File inputFile = new File("serialData.xlsx");
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

    DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("serialData.xlsx",DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
    System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());


 }
```

Comment: What do you mean that you "got stuck"? Did you paste the authorization code back into the app? Then what happened?

Comment: well "Enter this code into agri to finish the process" below this line u will be getting the auth code.to be frank i dont know how to proceed after that.how to use the auth code?i tried debugging,the program will stop at this point String code=....;

Comment: You should copy the code to the clipboard and paste it into the console window (where you're running your program). Then press enter.

Comment: it says connection timed out.

Comment: Is there any more to the `connection timed out`? Presumably you're seeing that on the console... is it part of an exception? Maybe with a stack trace? That can't possibly be happening on the call to `readLine()`, so you probably have some code after that. Please share the rest of your code.

Comment: @smarx i have edited ..this is were it fails "DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);"

Comment: I see no reason to think the error message isn't accurate. There's probably been a connection timeout. (This would usually indicate a networking problem.)

Comment: will check with that...

Comment: @smarx my proxy is blocking the file from getting upload...i tried using  System.setProperty but it isn't working,do you have any idea.Is there any other function within the api so that we can pass the proxy

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the sample app in for example Eclipse, your code execution will stop and wait for you to go get the authorization code (see readLine() prompt). You then paste this into the console in Eclipse (or any command prompt). Then the code will be passed to another method to get and "Access Token" which is another String. This is what you need to save to disk for future use. I change the code a little to show the String token that needs to be saved for future api calls.

```
//Include the Dropbox SDK.
import com.dropbox.core.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DbxException {
        // Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developers website.
        final String APP_KEY = "myappkey"; // change with yours
        final String APP_SECRET = "supersecret"; // change with yours

        DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaTutorial/1.0",
                Locale.getDefault().toString());
        DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);
        // Have the user sign in and authorize your app.
        String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();

        // System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
        // System.out
        // .println("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)");
        // System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");
        // String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
        // .readLine().trim();
        // DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);
        // System.out.println("Access token is:");
        // System.out.println(authFinish.accessToken.toString());

        // save the value of myToken to a file for future use
        String myToken = "mybigsecrettokenxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // change with
                                                                    // yours
        // DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, authFinish.accessToken);
        DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, myToken);
        System.out.println("Linked account: "
                + client.getAccountInfo().displayName);
        System.out.println("check1");
        File inputFile = new File("C:\\dev\\pi\\foo.txt");
        System.out.println("check2");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        System.out.println("check3");
        try {
            DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/main/fooup2.txt",
                    DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
            System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }

        DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren("/main");
        System.out.println("Files in the root path:");
        for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {
            System.out.println("    " + child.name + ": " + child.toString());
        }

        // download file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                "C:\\dev\\pi\\downloadedfile.txt");
        try {
            DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = client.getFile("/main/fooup2.txt",
                    null, outputStream);
            System.out.println("Metadata: " + downloadedFile.toString());
        } finally {
            outputStream.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: iam facing a new problem...my proxy is blocking the file from uploading. Error : "Connection timed out:connect"